# perfect scrollbar set maxScrollbarLength

Tags: scroll, scrollbar, perfect-scrollbar

I used this plugin https://github.com/noraesae/perfect-scrollbar and there is `minScrollbarLength` but I wana set `maxScrollbarLength` but I low in programing and i dont know where i can change this option so I ask for help.

my code in index

```
     <script>
          jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
            "use strict";
            $('#Default').perfectScrollbar({
                suppressScrollY: true,
                useBothWheelAxes: true,
                minScrollbarLength: 300,
                //and here i wana set maxScrollbarLength
            });
            $( ".ps-scrollbar-x" ).append( "<p>Drag This</p>" );
          });
     </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Perfect scrollbar does not support max-size as I know. You have to change plugin code or contact author and report this as a feature. Also you can try [jQuery Scrollbar](https://github.com/gromo/jquery.scrollbar) which supports it and has the same styles as perfect scrollbar.

Comment: Had a problems with a perfect-scrollbar (added fixed height to div, but scrollbar scrolled much lower than div). Used a jquery scrollbar and it worked fine. Thanx.